# Role Based Access Authorization in perfect

Tags: perfect

Being new to perfect server side swift, I cannot find any packages that help with role based access authorization. In Spring there is for example,

```
.antMatchers("/homePage").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
.antMatchers("/adminPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

Is there something already existing in perfect to help with this? Is there a recommended way of handling access control in perfect?

Answer (score 1):

As you use perfect server, you may take a look at:

- [PerfectlySoft Perfect-Authentication](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Authentication)
- [perfect.org authentication](https://perfect.org/docs/authentication.html)
- [perfect.org Turnstile](https://perfect.org/docs/Turnstile.html)

Comment: The https://github.com/PerfectSideRepos/Turnstile-Perfect/blob/master/Sources/AuthFilter.swift seems to be best starting point for a role/s based filter. Adding a role to the Account class to allow filtering on include/exclude routes.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect provides system level of authentication.

Firstly, you can go to github and search PerfectlySoft/Perfect-LocalAuthentication for user identity validation, however, it doesn't contain the role control as you asked.

It can be done in other approaches. For example, you can use Perfect-LDAP to access an LDAP server for all kinds of roles and groups.

Comment: Access groups/roles is not the issue. I suppose was looking for a requestFilter like AuthFilter that could include/exclude paths base on a role. The role itself could be pulled from the user record or other. It is strange if
 such a filter is not already available.